# How do I setup a build agent and restrict its use to one teams project?

Tags: team-foundation-server

How do I setup a build agent and restrict its use to one teams project in TFS2017?   I have searched the web and have found how I can send a build to a specific agent, but I'd like to restrict the agent to one project so other teams and projects cannot use the agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a three steps process:

1. You need to create a new Agent Pool **and** disable the *Auto-Provision Queues in all Projects* options.
2. Add the new Agent to this newly created pool,
3. finally create an Agent Queue in the target Team Project to expose the pool.

As @nschonni said, you can find the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/pools-queues.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a build pool for the project and add the agent to that pool. Pools can be restricted to particular projects. More specific instructions can be found in the docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/pools-queues